# Azure App Service - bandwidth limitations?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

In our development environment (in Azure) we are experiencing an issue which we are sure could be due to bandwidth limitations of the underlying VM. By scaling our App Service up a pricing level (from Basic to Standard), the issue stops occurring. Utilisation of the CPU, memory, connection, threads, are all very low.

**What are the actual network/bandwidth limitations for the different Azure App Service tiers?**

These pages provide nothing on the matter:

- [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits)
- [Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what the issue was that you were facing. 
There are other restrictions for Azure App Services, which are defined here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Most of the restrictions in Azure App Service are specific:

1. Size of the VM
2. Pricing Tier

The problem you described seems to be related to size than pricing tier.

Comment: The issue is posted [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/650). Upgrading from B1 to S3 solves the issue.

Comment: So you basically need more cores. B3 & S3 have same number of cores. So B3 should be suffice for you.
There are some add-ons in Standard tier which is not available in Basic.

Comment: I specifically would like to know the bandwidth limitations between these different VMs. Like I said in my question, utilisation of the CPU, memory, connection, threads, are all very low.

Comment: At the networking layer, the bandwidth is as per this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/

Comment: Forgot to mention that it has nothing to do with the size of the underlying VM.

Answer (score 0):

For free tiers, well explained here:

[App Service free quotas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bandwidth-quota-changes-to-the-free-offer-of-azure-app-service/)

All the free app services will stop working if bandwidth is the issue

Answer (score -1):

Less than 200MB daily, about 5GB per month